# render php code in view result

Tags: views

What's the proper method to render a field within the views?

In node templates I render php code using

```
echo render($content['fancy_field']);
```

But when I want to render php code within a view I was using

```
echo render($view->result->_field_data['nid']['entity']->fancy_field);
```

But it didn't works, any ideas?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use Views built-in field handlers to render the fields in your View? Are you referring to some "field" that isn't actually a proper [Field](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field)?

Comment: the markup it's a little complex, it's strange...I'm using php filter module, the field (text) is set to php code. But when you just 'echo' the field the php code it's commented.

Comment: when I print $rows in the template I can see the result including the php parsed but when I try to access to specific field using $view->result the php code disappear

Comment: Are you talking about the PHP Filter module in Core? It's not designed to display PHP code. It's purpose is to embed PHP code which is then actually run, not displayed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic functionality of the Views module and answerable by reading the [Views documentation](https://drupal.org/node/54448). If the desired functionality is not included in Views, a more detailed question is required.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to implement [hook_field_formatter_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) and [hook_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7). The [examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) shows how to do this in greater detail in the [field_example submodule](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_example!field_example.module/7).

Comment: seriously? just for print a field with php code within the view?

Comment: All that stuff is required only if you're creating a new type of field. There are a LOT of Field types available in both core and contrib which will work with Views without any extra work. It seems like you're not using an actual field here though, so maybe you could add more details about what it is you're trying to display.

Comment: I'm using a Long text field, this is the result when print the field

    Array
    (
        [es] =&gt; Array
            (
                [0] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [value] =&gt; Business Intelligence<!--?php echo url('node/96'); ?-->

                        [format] =&gt; php_code
                    )

            )

    )

Comment: Are you trying to change the formatting of the fields output? If not, why aren't you just letting Views handle displaying the field? --> Didn't see your comment on original question

Comment: I think that the error is here:

This is my array result:

    [es] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Business Intelligence <!--?php echo url('node/96'); ?-->

                    [format] => php_code
                )

        )

Comment: In drupal_render function....

    // Early-return nothing if user does not have access.
    if (empty($elements) || (isset($elements['#access']) && !$elements['#access'])) {
        return '';
    }

Comment: Since $view->result->_field_data['nid']['entity']->fancy_field doesn't have #access index the drupal don't render anything, so...how I can render php code in the view if the array don't have the necessary elements?

Comment: I would assume there's not `#access` element because the view has already determined if the field can be access, and so it included the field's content. Though I can't say I went through the Views code to confirm that.

Comment: You did ask what the proper method was. The implementation is roughly 20 lines of code across two functions, and I've linked directly to an example and described the functions that needed implementing. Anything worth doing is worth doing right, and storing executable code in the database is not a best practice. Please let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be glad to help.